# How does execvp inspect the PATH variable?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'm using execvp in my code and, the way I understand it, it directly invokes the command it is passed, unlike popen or system, which also invoke a shell.

But, I also understand that execvp inspects the `PATH` variable to look for the command it is passed in various directories, and this is also why I use it, so I don't have to pass the whole path of the program.

So how does execvp inspect the `PATH` variable if it does not even invoke a shell? My intuition tells me it could be because every process after logging in is an indirect child of a shell session, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The obvious underlying question in every question that contains explicit assumptions is "Are my assumptions wrong?". I wrote them the same way I think about them, I get that they're vague (poorly-specified), it's because I do only have a vague sense of what's going on. Anyhow, your comments kind of cleared it up, so thank you!

Comment: you might find https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227989/complete-view-of-where-the-path-variable-is-set-in-bash interesting @BaridunDuskhide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Environment Variables and Shell Variables Are Different

One common misconception, perhaps one on which this question is partially based, is that *all* shell variables are "environment variables".

This is not true: Shells have regular shell variables, stored in heap memory, not propagated across process boundaries, and otherwise local to that shell process; and they have *environment variables*, which have a copy maintained in the block of per-process memory managed by the kernel. There's a limit on the space available in this block (typically shared with command-line argument length -- more/larger environment variables means there's less space for command-line arguments), so allocating environment variables is "more expensive" than regular shell variables.

---

#### Environment Variables Are Copied To Child Processes On Creation, And Accessible By Non-Shell Software

When shell variables that are flagged as exported change, a typical shell written in C uses [`setenv()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html) or [`putenv()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putenv.html) to copy the new value into the process-information space.

This block of space is, like all other process state, copied on [`fork()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html), and preserved through [`exec*()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) calls that do not explicitly overwrite it; which is how environment variables are inherited by subprocesses.

**The `exec` specification linked above has detailed information on how environment variables are passed between and represented within C programs; reading it is strongly recommended.**

Any program can call `getenv()` (or implement similar functionality as the libc `getenv` implementation includes) to read the value of these variables.

---

#### Consequently, `execvp()` can be implemented in pure C, with no shell involved anywhere.

Typically this is a libc wrapper around a lower-level call like `execve` that directly instructs the kernel to replace the current process image with a new one; but one *could* also implement it directly in the kernel, as the kernel has access to the block of memory with process information that it handed off to its child, and can retrieve environment variables from there.

Answer (score 2):

> how does execvp inspect the PATH variable if it does not even invoke a shell?

From glibc sources https://github.com/zerovm/glibc/blob/master/posix/execvp.c#L93 first it just gets the variable from environment variables of the current process:

```
char *path = getenv ("PATH");
```

Then for each dir in path separated by colon:

```
path = p;
p = __strchrnul (path, ':');
```

It adds the "name" of the executable passed to `execvp` with the path from `PATH`. So for example you call `execvp("somexe", ...)` and `PATH=/dir1/dir2:/dir3/dir4`, the loop will run twice, first with `startp=/dir1/dir2/somexe` and then with `startp=/dir3/dir4/someexe`.

```
startp = (char *) memcpy (name - (p - path), path, p - path);
```

And then tries to call that to `execve` system call with that path + name part:

```
/* Try to execute this name.  If it works, execve will not return. */
__execve (startp, argv, __environ);
```

If kernel `execve` can find the path, it will run it, if it can't, it will fail with `ENOENT`:

```
    case ENOENT:
    case ESTALE:
    case ENOTDIR:
      /* Those errors indicate the file is missing or not executable
     by us, in which case we want to just try the next path
     directory.  */
    ...
     break;
```

The process of "taking a dir from PATH" and "adding it to name passed to execve" and then calling the system call `execve` is repeated for each dir in PATH.